# Creating Chart with data from another sheet and different number of columns

Tags: vba, excel, charts

My code should create one chart for every row of a data base. This data base is in a different sheet. Since that data base should change the number of columns I'm counting how many columns and changing the data source. Every time I run the code it comes with an error in the SetSourceData.

I couldn't find what am I doing wrong.

Can someone help me find a solution?

```
Sub createColumnChartMatriz12()

Dim ChartName As String
Dim Row As Integer
Dim ChartRow As Integer
Dim sh As Worksheet
Set sh = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matriz 1")
Dim k As Long
Dim z As Long

k = sh.Range("A1", sh.Range("A1").End(xlDown)).Rows.Count
z = sh.Cells(1, sh.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column - 4
ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Matriz1Chart").Select
Cells.Select
Selection.RowHeight = 15.5
Cells(1, 1).Select


ChartRow = 49
Row = 2
For Row = 2 To k

ChartName = "Utilização no Período " & sh.Cells(Row, 1).Value

ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart2(201, xlColumnClustered).Select

With ActiveChart
    .SetSourceData Source:=sh.Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, z)), _
            PlotBy:=xlRows
    .FullSeriesCollection(1).XValues = "='Matriz 1'!$D$1:$AM$1"
    .Parent.Height = Range("A1:A15").Height
    .Parent.Width = Range("A1:J1").Width
    .Parent.Top = Range("A" & ChartRow).Top
    .Parent.Left = Range("A" & ChartRow).Left
    .HasTitle = True
    .ChartTitle.Text = ChartName
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Meses"
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).HasTitle = True
    .Axes(xlValue, xlPrimary).AxisTitle.Characters.Text = "Utilização"
    .Axes(xlCategory, xlPrimary).TickLabels.NumberFormat = "mm-yyyy"
End With

ChartRow = ChartRow + 16

Next

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is your only problem, but when you access a Range by providing two cells (Cells are in fact also Ranges), you have to qualify these cells also.

Your statement `sh.Range(Cells(Row, 4), Cells(Row, z))` tries to define a `Range` object of sheet `"Matriz 1"` (saved in variable `sh`), but `Cells(Row, 4)` refers to the *active* sheet. That makes the range itself invalid and causes the failure of the `.SetSourceData` command.

You should write `sh.Range(sh.Cells(Row, 4), sh.Cells(Row, z))` instead. As a general advice: split the logic of such complicated command - it is much easier to debug and figure out what fails. In your case, first define the range, write it into a variable and after that assign it to the chart:

```
With ActiveChart
    dim chartRange as Range
    set chartRange = sh.Range(sh.Cells(Row, 4), sh.Cells(Row, z))

    .SetSourceData Source:=chartRange, PlotBy:=xlRows
    ...
end with
```

or, if you prefer (but note the leading `.`)

```
With ActiveChart
    dim chartRange as Range
    with sh 
        set chartRange = .Range(.Cells(Row, 4), .Cells(Row, z))
    end with
    .SetSourceData Source:=chartRange, PlotBy:=xlRows
    ...
end with
```